# Display only bounding box during dragging objects not the whole object (Fabric.js)

Tags: draggable, fabricjs

I am using fabric js and I only need to display the bounding box of an Object, not the whole object during dragging. Means to say Object would be fixed until I stops the dragging.

Comment: Actual there is no built-in support for something like that. But there is a open ticket: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/298.
Feel free to upvote it or add a bounty to that issue (https://www.bountysource.com/issues/55991-new-feature-for-moving-an-object-see-scrollkit-com).

Comment: can some one help me i have similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can inherite your own subclass from object with custom property "isMoving" or "isSelected", and implement _render function with if statement - call default _render or draw only bounding box somehow (for example try set transparency for object to 0). For canvas on "object:selected" or "object:moving" set "isMoving" true, and for "selection:clear" set to false.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions its working now and code is
canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
        activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        activeObject.setOpacity(0);
      });
      canvas.on('object:modified', function(options) {
        activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        activeObject.setOpacity(1);
      });